# equivalent of matlab bwconncomp and regionprops in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scikit-image, opencv

Im going to impliemnt a matlab code in python but there is some problem here is a pat of my matlab code which works perfect, here is my matlab code :

```
    mask=imerode(mask,strel('disk',3));
    I_enh=I_enh.*mask;
    BW = imregionalmax(I_enh);
    concomp = bwconncomp(BW);
    STATS = regionprops(concomp,'Centroid','PixelIdxList','Area');
    [R,C]=size(I_enh);
    w=100;
    feature=zeros(length(STATS),2);
```

I don't know how to convert `bwconncomp` and `regionprops` to python could anybody help me with this?
also `regionprops` has some method like `'Centroid','PixelIdxList','Area'` inside that I have no idea for implementation either!
there must be something similar in python I found `skimage.measure` in python but I don't know how to use it. help me, please!

Comment: `skimage.measure` is the right tool. There are thousands of examples out there, just do a bit of Googling.

Comment: could you tell me more please I want the exact value of matllab wich present in concomp and STATE. I don't even know what should I search at  google at least please give me some keyword body

Comment: You can use `area`, `centroid` and `coords` for your three properties.